# Vectorialised sums, with weights pulled from another tibble

Tags: dplyr, tibble, weighted

I have two tibbles, for example

```
library(tidyverse)

A <- tibble(
  G = c("A","A","B"),
  a = c("a", "b","c"),
  e = c(1, 2, 3))

Z <- tibble(
  i = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
  j = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
  z = c(1, .5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

I want to mutate values of `A$e` as follows:

I want that `e` is now the vectorised sum of all the columns `e`, weighted by the value of `Z$z` when `a == i` and `a == j`, grouped by `G`.

For example, for group `A`:

`z_sum_e <- c( 1*1 + 2*.5, 1*0 + 2*1)`

I think there are many ways to do it, and using a pre-packaged function like `weighted.sum` could make it easier to code, because it will reduce the complexity of the task to just filter and pull the right `nrow(A)` weights from `Z$z`, then `map` the mutate for `e`, considering that the column `e` is always the same, the only thing that changes is the vector of weights.

For example,

```
A %>%
  mutate(w = map(a,
                 ~ Z$z[Z$i == .x & Z$j %in% a]),
         .by = "G")
```

with this code I have to just sum always the same column `e` grouped by `G`, the vectorialisation would be on the adopted weights `w`.

I would like a fast solution, as the dataset has roughly half a million of rows, grouped, with approximately 5 rows per group.

Comment: Hi Giulio! 1. what is c? 2. how large is the original dataset? Are you running it on millions of rows, or literally millions of times?

Comment: A possible value of i or j. In A there is no a=="c", but in a hypothetical B there could be a a=="c".

Comment: The dataset is roughly half a million of rows, but grouped in clusters of, more or less, 5 rows per group. So, more or less, each value of e should be replaced by another valued which is more or less the sum of 5 values (always the same per group). What changes are the weights in the sum. The weights are all stored in Z.

I would avoid to expand the tibble with the values.

Comment: okay, thanks for sharing that! another question- are the values in the original dataset completely random, or have they been precomputed based on something else?

Comment: I don't understand this last question.
They are computed from other values, but fair to assume e is a random variable (grouped, etc.)

Comment: what I mean to say is, if (for example) there has been some kind of complicated method which just creates some kind of permutations behind the scenes, rather than you turning it into a dataframe of characters, then me turning those back into objects, and then parsing them, then it would be faster for me to incorporate that creation algorithm into the code itself (e.g. using map)

Comment: you said c is 'A possible value of i or j', but its value in the example is 3

Comment: what is the value of c meant to be in the first group?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I am sticking with the following code:

```
A %>%
  mutate(w = map(a,
                 ~ Z$z[Z$i == .x & Z$j %in% a]),
         .by = "G") %>%
  mutate(e = map_dbl(w, ~ sum(.x * e)),
         .by = "G")
```

I still don't know how fast this is going to be, so maybe you can make it faster.